# Sharepoint 2013 PageTitle

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a Sharepoint Subsite that I use as a template and I have modified the homepage by creating a new page with the layout of webparts that fit my needs by using default layouts.

I then set this new page to my default homepage of my template subsite and saved it out as a template. Created a new subsite using this template and everything looks good except the page title at the top. It used to display the subsite name rather than the name of the page.

My questions is how do I get the pagetitle to show the subsite name such as CL6001 instead of displaying HOME or can I add it as a suffix to the page title.

Right now it displays Home and the url looks like this

/Project/CL6001/Pages/Home.aspx

I would prefer that it had CL6001 as the pagetitle.

If this is not possible can I edit the masterpage for the default.aspx to have more webpart zone areas? I essentially need to have 4 zones on the default.aspx page to make my layout work. I need a top left / top right and a middle left / middle right area to add Sharepoint Libraries and Lists to.

My page looks like this

Top Left - Sharepoint Library
Top Right - Sharepoint List
Middle Left - Sharepoint List
Middle Right- Sharepoint List

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For case 2.
No need to modify your master page for single page.Create one Page Layout add your layout html along with Webpart zones. Create your default.aspx page with newly created page layout.